# Covert CSV to YAML in python for Nornir inventory

Tags: python, csv, yaml

I need to generate a yaml inventory file for Nornir from a CSV of devices.

Input:

```
ip,model,firmware,serial
192.168.0.1,JXXXA,K.16.10.9999,SGXXXXX123
192.168.0.2,JXXXB,KB.16.10.1111,SGXXXXX456
```

Desired output:

```
JXXXA-SGXXXXX123:
    hostname: "192.168.0.1"
    data:
        model: "JXXXX"
        fimrware: "K.16.10.9999"
        serial: "SGXXXXX123"

JXXXB-SGXXXXX456:
    hostname: "192.168.0.2"
    data:
        model: "JXXXB"
        fimrware: "KB.16.10.1111"
        serial: "SGXXXXX456"
```

Currently I'm thinking I'd generate some type of nested dictionary, but I'm guessing there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Read the csv in a dict, and then export it with a yaml library

Comment: Yeah I think I just came upon a tutorial that will help me figure it out. Ty!